# How to use X11 cursors on Windows?

Tags: windows, cursor, mouse-cursor

I am a big fan of the `redglass` cursor scheme that is available on Unix systems. I want to use the cursor theme on Windows too, however, it uses a whole different format of cursors. Is there any way I can convert or load X11 cursors for usage in Windows operating systems?

Comment: They can't natively be used in Windows, you'll have to find a conversion tool.  There are some out there, but product recommendations are off-topic on Superuser.

Comment: @squillman, the very problem is that I am unable to find a conversion tool that converts Linux cursors to Windows, while it is fairly easy to find a tool that does it the other way. Maybe am I looking wrong?